# Por que não posso fazer o hash da senha no meu método seed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, criptografia, senhas

Estou tentando usar meu método `seed` abaixo para criar um usuário no banco de dados quando ele é criado:

```
protected override void Seed(CodingCraftMod1Ex4AuthMembershipContext context)
{
    string password = PasswordsHelper.EncodePassword("123456", System.Web.Security.MembershipPasswordFormat.Hashed);

    var user = new CustomUser
    {
        CustomUserId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = "MyUser",
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
        LastModified = DateTime.Now
    };

    context.CustomUsers.Add(user);
    context.SaveChanges();

    var membership = new Membership
    {
        MembershipId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        CustomUser = user,
        Password = password,
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
        LastModified = DateTime.Now,
    };

    context.Memberships.Add(membership);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Mas recebo o seguinte erro:**

> Hashed or Encrypted passwords are not supported with auto-generated keys

Eu já estou usando o elemento `machineKey`, assim:

```
<machineKey   validationKey="13687AD58719815734D5ECA97AADA159F4084FE994E32192243818A714DD6BC763B9F3D8AE7B3A7858A268D8EAAB37BF5031E77E5971C82BC1ACEA478C76C6CF" 
decryptionKey="A39F3B62B3CAAD3F75358197CA1D880BA3F392BE79AE4E91D2A09219D82A6978"
validation="SHA1" 
decryption="AES" />
```

Eu usei [essa ferramenta online](http://developmentnow.com/articles/machinekey_generator.aspx) para gerar as chaves.

Segue abaixo o trecho personalizado do método que faz o hash da senha no método `EncodePassword`:

```
case MembershipPasswordFormat.Hashed:
    HMACSHA1 hash = new HMACSHA1();
    hash.Key = HexToByte(machineKey.ValidationKey);
    encodedPassword =
        Convert.ToBase64String(hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password)));
    break;
```

Comment: você personalizou a geração do password do membership? Ela provavelmente está no formato "Clear" e não Hashed. Pode passar a configuração? Você está usando que tecnologia?

Comment: Editei a pergunta com mais alguns detalhes. Não entendi bem que tecnologia quer que eu especifique, mas qualquer dúvida é só perguntar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não encontrei uma forma de fazer funcionar o hash usando meu código personalizado do Membership.

É até óbvio, mas vou deixar a forma que contornei isso. Ao invés de usar o trecho abaixo:

```
string password = PasswordsHelper.EncodePassword("123456", System.Web.Security.MembershipPasswordFormat.Hashed);
```

Eu simplesmente fiz o Hash da senha que queria usar para o usuário criado no seed e coloquei direto no método, já como Hash:

```
string password = "h+V92o4VkQjWgegKgqwprJ2PUFU=";
```